# How to load images loading.gif before load iframe in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a Jquery code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.basic').click(function (e) {
        var loading = '<img src="loading.gif"/>';
            $('<div></div>').load(loading);
        var src = 'test.php';
            var html = '<iframe src="'+src+'&output=embed" style="border:0"></iframe>';
            $.modal(html);
            return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

How to load a image loading.gif before load a iframe ?

Comment: If you want the loading.gif to show somewhere, you would need to actually put it in your page.  As you have it now, it doesn't show because it's not in the page.  The best way to have an image like this loaded in advance of a click is to put the image in a div in your actual page (so the image is loaded when the page is loaded) and make it display: none initially.  Then, when you want to show it, you just use .show() on it and the image is already loaded and it's already in the page.

Comment: You're also not using `.load()` correctly.  It doesn't take an HTML string.  It takes a URL to do an ajax call from and inserts the result.  That's not what you want here.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
jQuery(function ($)
{
    $('.basic').click(function (e)
    {
        $('<img />').bind('bind',function()
        {
            var src = 'test.php';
            var html = '<iframe src="'+src+'&output=embed" style="border:0"></iframe>';
            $.modal(html);
        }).attr('src','loading.gif');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.basic').click(function (e) {
        var loading = '<img src="loading.gif"/>';

        $('<div></div>').load(loading, function() {
        var src = 'test.php';
            var html = '<iframe src="'+src+'&output=embed" style="border:0"></iframe>';
            $.modal(html);
            return false;
    }); //end of loading the image
  }); //end of loading the iframe
});
</script>
```